# merge properties from two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

I have this code:

```
   IEnumerable<CarResultsViewModel> priceResults = price.Select(p => new CarResultsViewModel
                    {
                        PricePerDay = p.PricePerDay,
                        PricePerDayDelayed = p.PricePerDayDelayed,
                        TotalPrice = (double)p.Total_price
                    }).ToList();

   IEnumerable<CarResultsViewModel> results = car.Select(c => new CarResultsViewModel
                    {
                        CreationYear = c.CreationYear,
                        ManufacturerName = c.ManufacturerName,
                        ModelName = c.ModelName,
                        Gear = c.Gear,
                        CurrentKm = c.CurrentKM,
                        Picture = c.Picture,
                        StartDate = model.StartDate,
                        ReturnDate = model.ReturnDate
                    }).ToList();
```

I would like to implement the three properties in priceResults into the results list. is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: You probably have a common Id which is the relation between the two objects? You could then join based on that Id.

Comment: You most likely need to use Join extension method for IEnumerable but you need some id correspondence between these two lists (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549267(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't have a common id. totally different objects , just the same type.

Answer (score -1):

The commentors are correct, you can use the JOIN function of LINQ to "merge" these two lists together, such as:

```
            var carResults = (from pr in priceResults
            join r in results
                on pr.CarId equals r.CarId
            select new CarResultsViewModel
            {
                CarId = pr.CarId,
                PricePerDay = pr.PricePerDayDelayed,
                ManufacturerName = r.ManufacturerName,
                etc...
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried you answer based on different common property and it added the objects from both priceResults and results to a new big list. Instead, I want to implement three object properties from the first list to the object properties in the second list.

Comment: What is the common thread between the two lists? How will you know which three properties from object A to add to which object in the other list?